# my data is null and not set

Tags: android, fragment

I see the following error in the log. I now what the problem is in the mContact not being set and is null. I am stuck and have been working on it the whole night.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String
>   com.bignerdranch.android.adressbook.Contact.getName()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                            at
>   com.bignerdranch.android.adressbook.ContactFragment.onCreateView(ContactFragment.java:80)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)

and the line that fails is line 80 in the ContactFragment

I have the code of that fragmetn as follows

```
import static android.widget.CompoundButton.*;

public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_CRIME_ID = "crime_id";
    private Contact mContact;//to hold the views current crime
    private TextView nameTextView; // displays contact's name
    private TextView phoneTextView; // displays contact's phone
    private TextView emailTextView; // displays contact's email
    private TextView streetTextView; // displays contact's street
    private TextView cityTextView; // displays contact's city
    private TextView stateTextView; // displays contact's state
    private TextView zipTextView; // displays contact's zip
    private Callbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Required interface for hosting activities.
     */
    public interface Callbacks {
        void onContactUpdated(Contact contact);
    }


    public static ContactFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID, crimeId);

        ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UUID contactId =  (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID);
        mContact = ContactLab.get(getActivity()).getContact(contactId);
        Log.d("m","oncreate of contactFragment");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

        // get the EditTexts
        nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        phoneTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneTextView);
        emailTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
        streetTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.streetTextView);
        cityTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityTextView);
        stateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stateTextView);
        zipTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zipTextView);
       nameTextView.setText(mContact.getName());


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        ContactLab.get(getActivity())
                .updateContact(mContact);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }

    }






    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_details_menu, menu);
    }

    // handle menu item selections
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:

                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                UUID contacId=(UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID);
                Contact contact =ContactLab.get(getActivity()).getContact(contacId);
                ContactLab.get(getActivity()).deleteContact(contact);
                getActivity().finish();
                return true;

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I need to know where my errors are why cant I set the textView to a value.

thankyou

Comment: You know what the problem is - `mContact` is null when you call `mContact.getName()`, so whatever you are using to populate that field (`ContactLab`?) isn't working correctly.

You'll need to do some debugging to narrow the scope of the problem first. Print some Log statements or use your IDE's debugger to find locations where you think `mContact` shouldn't be null, but is.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this exception because mContact is null. You have to create object of contact than you can access without any problem.

Add this to your onCreateView before set value to textview

```
UUID contacId=(UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID); 
mContact =ContactLab.get(getActivity()).getContact(contacId)
nameTextView.setText(mContact.getName());
```